# PHP wordpress string formatting error

Tags: php, string, wordpress

I have a bit of PHP where I want to store a URL in a string.
The code itself seems fine, but for some reason, when I use the characters `$sectionId=`, it causes problems, in fact, it alters `$sectionId=` and changes it to `§ionId=`.

If I misspell it to `$secionId` then it works fine.

The full url SHOULD be:

```
http://url.com/file.php?appKey=$appkey&storeId=$storeid&sectionId=$sectionid&v=3
```

but when I do an `echo $myURL;` on it, it gives me:

```
http://url.com/file.php?appKey=$appkey&storeId=$storeid§ionId=$sectionid&v=3
```

Notice the `§ionId=` instead of `$sectionId=`.

Can anyone help me with this? It seems like basic PHP, but I don't understand why it just doesnt like those 4 or 5 characters in a row!!

Thanks.

Comment: What version of php are you using, and do you have a locale specified that could be causing a unicode conversion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you echoing it right to HTML? Well, some over-helpful browsers will do character conversions without being asked explicitly to with a semicolon; all you need to do is run it through `htmlentities` or replace all `&`s with `&amp;` and it will display correctly.

Comment: Hmm, so what will happen if i just process the string as normal? Is it ONLY when I echo the string that the browser is doing a conversion?

Comment: Yes, most likely. Using it within PHP will be fine.